# How to select column based on criteria from INCLUDEd table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am selecting a set of data from sql database table1, based on the Id of each row selected in table 1, i am including all rows that have same id in table 2, for each of those rows i want to select only the rows(from table 2) where a column say (mobile) has a value of 1

This is entityframework related, here's the query below

```
List<Event> queryEvents;
using (var context = new Entities())
{
   queryEvents = context.Events.Where(s => s.IsActive == (byte?) RecordTypeEnum.Active)
                    .Include(s => s.EventOwner).Include(x => x.EventTickets.Any(y => y.AvailableInventory >= 1))
                    .Where(g => g.IsActive != null && g.EventOwner.IsActive == true)
                    .OrderByDescending(h => h.EventOwnerId).ThenBy(j => j.Title).ToList();
}
```

Error Message -

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
>   Parameter name: path

I want to select all records from table1 where IsActive (column) == 1 and select all records from table2 where table1 id = table2 id and where AvailableInventory (column) in table 2 == 1

Comment: Conditional Include is **NOT** supported by entity framework. There are some 3rd party tools that able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Include is not supported. But you can achieve your goal with the code below;

```
  queryEvents = context.Events.Where(s => s.IsActive == (byte?) RecordTypeEnum.Active)
                    .Include(s => s.EventOwner)
    .Select(e => new{
    e, 
    EventTicklets = e.EventTickets.Where(y => y.AvailableInventory >= 1 ).ToList()
})
                    .Where(g => g.e.IsActive != null && g.e.EventOwner.IsActive == true)
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on this part of the select clause, EventTickets = e. Is the EventTickets meant to be a reference to the class or db table?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the question in a single query so i used two queries

```
queryEvents = context.Events.Where(s => s.IsActive == (byte?)RecordTypeEnum.Active)
                    .Include(s => s.EventOwner).Include(x => x.EventTickets)
                    .Where(g => g.IsActive == (byte)RecordTypeEnum.Active && g.EventOwner.IsActive == true)
                    .OrderByDescending(h => h.EventOwnerId).ThenBy(j => j.Title);

                queryEvents = queryEvents.Select(o =>
                {
                    o.EventTickets = o.EventTickets.Where(f => f.AvailableInventory > 0 && f.Amount != zero ).ToList();
                    return o;
                }).ToList();
```

in the first query, i selected all events and included the tickets table, then in the second query, i selected all events where a field in the the tickets object met the specified criteria